# What is the complexity of elgamal cryptosystem?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, cryptography

Its clear generation of keys based
On cyclic group and its generator for z_p
So my question
Does finding the generator efect on complexity
Moreove does the size of message M effect on the complexity?

Comment: Please provide the background and make the question self-contained.